# Drag and Drop a file for opening it: when to make does this work in case of administrator?

Tags: windows-10

When I want to open a file in an application, I have the habit to do this by dragging the file from the Windows explorer, and dropping it inside the application (which I have already opened before). This works for lots of applications (Notepad, Notepad++, MS-Word, MS-Excel, ...), and MS-Word even has different behaviours (in case nothing is open, then open the file, else embed the file inside of the already opened file).

This however seems not to work for the mentioned applications when they are started as `administrator`, which I find quite annoying.

Is there a way to say to Windows that it must allow its applications to open files, even in the case they are `drag- and dropped` into the application?

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature called [User Interface Privilege Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation). It was added to windows after Vista.

It disallows applications to communicate via the UI from a lower elevation (e.g. Windows Explorer as a standard user) to higher a level elevation (Your application run as administrator). However it works the other way (Higher to Lower) and clipboard is shared regardless.

As far as I know, there is no real workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

To run Windows Explorer as Administrator *by itself* doe not work, but [a similar effect can be achieved by opening *another* application as Administrator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170328-00/?p=95845) and using its *File - Open* or *File - Save* dialog for drag/drop. E.G.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>.
- Type `notepad.exe`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Click `Yes` in the UAC dialog.
- In *Notepad*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to use the *File - Open* dialog. Files can be dragged from this dialog to another application that is being run as Administrator.

*Caveat:* With privilege comes responsibility -- using Explorer as Administrator gives one the opportunity to delete system files or make other changes that could mess up a PC.

Comment: I expected this would be the answer, but when I tested it on W10/1709 with an elevated Notepad it didn't work. It turns out that the reason for this is that opening Explorer as Administrator doesn't run as expected: it opens a new thread in the existing Explorer, which runs with current privileges, so dragging and dropping still works only on the unelevated Notepad.

Comment: The only way round I have found is to use an alternative file manager - I used [Explorer++](https://explorerplusplus.com/) and this receives elevated privileges when requested, though I was surprised to find that the elevated Explorer++ could drag and drop to an unelevated Notepad as well. As a footnote, I used the [Portable Apps version](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/explorerplusplus_portable), rather than doing a new installation.

Comment: @AFH, thanks for pointing out my error... but I've altered the answer and *tested* it, this time, to achieve the same results. Admittedly, this is a bit of a kluge, requiring an additional application be kept open. Third-party explorer replacements such as Q-Dir, Free Commander and Explorer++ also work, as you point out.

Comment: Good point about using an open dialogue: it avoids the necessity of a third-party application, which many people don't like or can't use because of policy settings.